# Eloquent ORM - retrieve models not related to the given model (Many to Many relationship)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So, I can eager load thus:

```
$subscribers = Subscriber::with('lists')->get();
```

and I am home and dry.
But now I want to do what in English would read:

```
$non_subscribers = Subscriber::without('thislist')->get();
```

And that doesn't read very well but hopefully it helps communicate what I aim to achieve. I could do two queries to first get all subscribers that have (and belong to) this list followed by another one to retrieve all subscribers; and then subtract one from another.

My question: is it possible to do it as eloquently as it is to put it in plain English like above?

Thanking you

Comment: The with method eager load the lists relation for the Subscriber.
So the without will not eager load (logically). So it's like never calling with.

What you are looking for is the inverse of the has method (which return relations that has a given relation). Infortunately, I don't think that is possible in an eloquent way.

Comment: Thanks, I have had to bite the bullet on that one and come up with a two-step solution. I will include it as an answer in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use the little known [whereDoesntHave](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereDoesntHave) method:

```
$subscribers = Subscriber::whereDoesntHave('lists', function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->whereId($id);
})->get();
```

or even a simplified version of your original answer:

```
$subscribers = Subscriber::whereNotIn('id', $list->subscribers->lists('id'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if you have a better solution, kindly let us know. At the moment, this one does the trick:

```
    $list = Addressbook::with('subscribers')->find($id);
    $subscribers = '';

    if ($list->subscribers->count() > 0)
    {
        $subs_array = array();

        foreach ($list->subscribers as $list_subscriber) 
        {
            $subs_array[] = $list_subscriber->id;
        }

        $subscribers = Subscriber::whereNotIn('id', $subs_array)->get(); //the clever bit
    }

    else
    {
        $subscribers = Subscriber::get();
    }


    return Response::json($subscribers);
```